# How to set SubstructureRedirect event mask on the root window using xcb python for a X11 window manager

Tags: python, x11, xcb

I have this code that does not give any exception, but I do not seem to be receiving events like MapRequests, or ConfigureNotifys:

```
import xcb
import xcb.xproto as xproto
conn = xcb.connect()
root = conn.get_setup().roots[0].root
eventmask = [xproto.EventMask.SubstructureRedirect, xproto.EventMask.SubstructureNotify]
conn.core.ChangeWindowAttributesChecked(self.root, xproto.CW.EventMask, eventmask)
while True:
    e = conn.wait_for_event()
    print e
```

I am testing this in Xephyr.

Am I doing something wrong? And if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: Could you post minimal reproducible code? Looks ok to me. Does server send any errors back? Note that only one client is allowed to set SubstructureRedirect mask of a given window and if you still have window manager running it probably owns that mask.

Comment: @AndreySidorov I haven't checked for errors, but I will. When I tried it in the interactive interpretor it returned a void cookie.

Comment: ChangeWindowAttributes request does not return data (thus void cookie), but could result in errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit:
  the problem is in incorrect number of parameters: `xproto.CW.EventMask` indicates that you have one value and you are passing two as `[xproto.EventMask.SubstructureRedirect, xproto.EventMask.SubstructureNotify]` which should be `[xproto.EventMask.SubstructureRedirect|xproto.EventMask.SubstructureNotify]`

```
import xcb
import xcb.xproto as xproto
conn = xcb.connect()
root = conn.get_setup().roots[0].root
conn.core.ChangeWindowAttributesChecked(self.root, xproto.CW.EventMask, [xproto.EventMask.SubstructureRedirect|xproto.EventMask.SubstructureNotify])
while True:
    e = conn.wait_for_event()
    print e
```

Comment: I updated my question to include that I am testing in Xephyr, and there are no other window managers running.

Comment: this code works fine for me in Xephyr (in OSX/Quartz): https://gist.github.com/3354128 - JavaScript+github.com/sidorares/node-x11 . I'll try to install python-xcb and run your example

Comment: I just tried it in the interactive interpreter and got this:       `>>> err = conn.core.ChangeWindowAttributesChecked(root, xproto.CW.EventMask, eventmask)
>>> err.check()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
xcb.xproto.BadLength: <xcb.xproto.LengthError object at 0x7f540f5c4998>`

Comment: that is strange. BadLength means that request is not serialised properly (with two events mask it should be exactly (3+2)*4 bytes length )

Comment: removing SubstructureNotify fixed the problem, not sure why

Comment: not sure about python-xcb api, but are you expected to have mask as one single parameter? xproto.EventMask.SubstructureRedirect|xproto.EventMask.SubstructureNotify instead of xproto.EventMask.SubstructureRedirect, xproto.EventMask.SubstructureNotify

Comment: Thats probably it: first parameter ( xproto.CW.EventMask in your case) tells how many values you have (one). EventMask is single parameter - 32bit events flags value.